# feature selection within large dataset

Tags: feature-selection, large-data

I have a dataset containing more than 1000 predictors and I would like to do the feature selection. The features belong to several big categories(geographical factors, customer information....etc) When I do the feature selection, I split the dataset into several sub-dataset, and each sub-dataset contains one category of information and the target variable. I did the feature selection within each sub-dataset rather than running algorithm on the whole dataset.

However, I can't find any reference which could support my approach. Could anyone suggest what reference I can use to back up this approach?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do any feature selection at all? Why not include all of them?

Comment: Surely feature-selection is a reasonable goal in and of itself, @Dave? Anyhow, I have to admit @Charlotte that this approach doesn't make sense to me. What's the motivation for splitting them up by category? This will miss all of the interrelations between the different categories, and may end up with redundant selections.

Comment: @JohnMadden For what purpose? Improving model fit?

Comment: @Dave The purpose of feature selection is increased interpretability.

Comment: @JohnMadden, Many thanks for your comments. Cause I though if they are important features within each category, they are also the important features for the whole dataset? It is like we put several groups of important features together to form the set of important features. But I didn't consider the interaction effect between different categories. Now, I have put them together and run the random forest.

Comment: @Dave, some complex algorithms will be fitted later, therefore I would like to screen out some unimportant features! Many thanks for your comment!

Comment: But you don't know which features will be important for a complex model by finding the features that are important for a simple model.

Comment: @Dave, Thanks for that! I fitted a random forest for finding important features, this is due to the time manner of my project and the computation power of R. Unfortunately I don't have time to wait for 3 days for a model, So I have to do feature selection. The rest models I am going to fit is some data mining algorithms, I assume they are as complex as the random forest.

Comment: Ah! I almost put "computational reasons" as a second purpose for feature selection :). Yes, it's true that there will doubtless be features that are good for a simple model but bad for a complex model and vice versa. But it's definitely not an absurd idea to take that approach :)

Anyways, Charlotte, the "problem" with the approach you describe is that you might pick two variable in different groups that essentially represent the same thing. I have problem in quotes because it's not the end of the world to have redundancy.